# Why use a slide rule and not an electronic calculator?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, props, the-wire

In Season 2 Episode 2 of [The Wire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/) at around 31:30, we see a guy (forensic medical examiner?) use a slide rule. Why not use a normal electronic calculator? I'm not really familiar with the show - is there some reason in the show why he would have a slide rule?

Here is my theory - is this off-base? I understand that the show's writers went to great lengths to depict everything realistically. I also know that forensic medical examiners use custom-made nomographs and sliding calculators to make quick calculations without having to memorize formulas and do math by hand. (See for example https://www.google.com/search?q=forensic+nomogram) These are stripped-down ultra-simplified single-purpose calculating instruments which sometimes have sliding parts, but are not slide rules. Slide rules are complicated general-purpose calculators and much harder to use.

So maybe the writers heard from somewhere that forensic medical examiners use sliding calculators, and either they or the props people misunderstood and gave the guy a real old-fashioned slide rule instead?

Any chance the writers ever mentioned this in interviews?

[image]

Comment: Slide rules are not complicated.  They are simpler and quicker to use than many pocket calculators.

Comment: I know exactly how complicated a slide rule is. No sensible person would use one in the mid 2000s to do important work unless there was some good reason. And I can't imagine what a good reason would be in this setting.

Comment: Some people like to use what tools they've learned with, it's more comfortable for them.

Comment: The guy in the show looks to be in his 40s, and the show is set in the 2000s. A slide rule in this situation is not believable, right? I'm not trying to argue, but I remember 2005- if I saw a guy in 2005 using a slide rule, I absolutely would've thought it was strange. And a background character on a TV show? Maybe for a quirky old guy it would make sense, but the thing sticks out like a sore thumb and begs for an explanation.

Comment: I don't know.  I was in my late 30s then and I was literally the first year in my high school to be allowed to use an electronic calculator in some of my math classes.  Someone 5-10 years older than me might have learned how to use a slide rule first.

Comment: Even so, it appears a little anachronistic to me - even someone who learns to use a slide rule can easily learn to use a calculator.  It's not like this was set in the 1960s.  But its not inconceivable that they just prefer it.

Comment: “No sensible person would use a slide rule…” I wonder if you’re overestimating how many people are sensible.

Comment: Cheap hand calculators came along soon after I learned to use a slide rule.  Pretty sure I never afterward saw anyone, of whatever age, use a slide rule other than to demonstrate its principle.

Comment: "it taught you how to estimate the correct order of magnitude of the answer. You needed that to put the decimal point in the right place. But it turns out that's a valuable skill you need routinely so you can check (*) the results of whatever you did with your calculator (or Matlab or Mathematica) where a small input error (or 2) may be missed given the "precision" of the computed result"

Comment: "[Calculators] could give an answer that was too precise, leaving one between the 2 of the choices given on the multiple choice exam. However, if worked out using circular slide rule (which is the heart of the E6B) the correct answer could be found." – [Does anyone teach logarithms via slide rules?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17669/does-anyone-teach-logarithms-via-slide-rules)